# How to assign variables in a derived class based on values of variables in an object of the base class?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

Recently at work I came across this code (this is a contrived example, but is fundamentally doing the same thing):

```
class A
{
public:
    int foo;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    int bar;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo = 1000;

    B b;
    A* a_ptr = &b;
    *a_ptr = a;
}
```

Above, what is happening is that all member variables in `a` are being copied into the corresponding member variables in `b`, since `B` is derived from `A` and all objects of type `B` are guaranteed to have at least all of the same member variables as objects of type `A`.

In the actual code, `A` has enough variables that manually assigning each of them would not be ideal.

After struggling with it for a little bit, I was able to make sense of what the code was doing, but the fact that it took me more than a couple seconds seems like a red flag.

Is there another way to do what this code is doing that might be easier to understand, or more in line with C++ common practices? Is it common to see variables assigned in this way?

Edit: It has been suggested that my question is a possible duplicate, and that I am asking what object slicing is. This is not object slicing, as I am not at any point assigning an object of the derived type to an object of the base type. As such, no information is "sliced" or lost anywhere in the code.

Comment: Why not overload the assignment operators?

Comment: @Nathan Overload to do what?

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify that this is not object slicing. This is sort of the opposite of object slicing. Please read the code carefully.

Comment: @NeilButterworth To do the assignment.  They can add a `derived& operator=(base& b)` and then they can assign a base to a derived.

Comment: @NathanOliver An overloaded assignment operator would certainly work. However, I worry that readers might make incorrect assumptions about what the assignment operator is doing, rather than bothering to actually look at the overloaded assignment operator.

Answer (score 3):

I would say using pointer operations like this to do the assignment is in fact uncommon in C++.

An alternate approach would be explicitly spelling out your intention with a cast. I'm not totally sure if it's more readable:

```
A a;
a.foo = 1000;

B b;
static_cast<A&>(b) = a;
```

Depending on your specific needs however you might be better served with a child constructor that takes a parent and constructs itself appropriately. That way you don't need to default construct the child and then assign the parent members as a second step.

Comment: While this is a more readable way of writing the example, it doesn't address the question. It seems to me like this should be a comment.

Comment: I think your code might be a little more readable, but still seems a bit confusing. Do you feel that using a child constructor would be a more common practice/readable way of accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 1):

If `a_ptr` serves no other purpose than as a temporary to assign `A` class members to the `B` object and later code only use `b`, I would suggest creating a constructor for `B` that takes an `A` object. If nothing else, it provides better readability than what is currently there.

```
class A
{
public:
    int foo;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B(const A &a)
    {
       A* a_ptr = this;
       *a_ptr = a;
    }
    int bar;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo = 1000;

    // Create B with copy of 'a' members
    B b(a);
}
```